# Unable to get resque 2.0.0.pre.1 to work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resque

I have added the line to my Gemfile:

```
gem 'resque', :git => 'https://github.com/resque/resque.git'
```

And I have created `config/initializers/resque.rb`:

but it is failing on the first line:

```
require 'resque/server'
```

With:

```
cannot load such file -- resque/server
```

I know it is installed because of the output from `bundle`:

```
Using resque (2.0.0.pre.1) from https://github.com/resque/resque.git (at master)
```

This used to work when I was using the defunkt github repo, but that is now gone.

Comment: what if you run `bundle exec rake` or whatever you are running to get this error?

Comment: That is how I get the error I posted above.